# Energy Costs Over Time by Source

Tags: data-request, energy

I'm looking for a comparison I can make between "traditional" energy sources and solar energy. This is remarkably difficult to find.

I would to have data on energy cost by source over time (in the years, i.e. 20 yeras would be great).

Ideally, I'd like to show how much solar energy has to come down in price before it is cheaper than, say, gas and the rate at which this has been currently happening.

Any advice would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Excel file is a bit complicated, but one source of this data comes from the [NREL 2018 Annual Technology Baseline](https://atb.nrel.gov/) (ATB)

Download like to [Excel file](https://data.nrel.gov/files/89/2018-ATB-data-interim-geo.xlsm) (with macros).

Each Sheet in the file is for a specific energy source:

[image]

These sheets also have future projections for each technology. You can find previous years at their [archive](https://atb.nrel.gov/electricity/archives.html). The most useful way to compare technologies is probably *LCOE* - [Levelized Cost of Energy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cost_of_electricity_by_source) ($/MWh).

---

The data from ATB and some others has been aggregated by [OpenEI.org](https://openei.org) and is available as the *Transparent Cost Database*, both with an [online viewer](https://openei.org/apps/TCDB/transparent_cost_database) and as a CSV or Excel data download.

[image]